# Retrofit : java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using two kind of interceptor, one is **HttpLoggingInterceptor** and another one is my custom **AuthorizationInterceptor**

I am using below updated retrofit version library,

```
def retrofit_version = "2.7.2"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.0'
```

below is code

```
private fun makeOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(AuthorizationInterceptor(context)) <---- To put Authorization Barrier
            .addInterceptor(logger) <---- To log Http request and response
            .followRedirects(false)
            .connectTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
    }
```

When I try to execute below code, in file named SynchronizationManager.kt, it gives me an error.

```
var rulesResourcesServices = RetrofitInstance(context).buildService(RulesResourcesServices::class.java)
val response = rulesResourcesServices.getConfigFile(file).execute() <---In this line I am getting an exception... (which is at SynchronizationManager.kt:185)
```

My RulesResourcesServices class is here

After debug I found that when below function called, at that time I am getting an exception

```
@GET("users/me/configfile")
    fun getConfigFile(@Query("type") type: String): Call<ResponseBody>
```

I am getting following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.kt:184)
at okio.ForwardingSource.read(ForwardingSource.kt:29)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$ExceptionCatchingResponseBody$1.read(OkHttpCall.java:288)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.readAll(RealBufferedSource.kt:293)
at retrofit2.Utils.buffer(Utils.java:316)<------- ANDROID IS HIGH-LIGHTING
at retrofit2.BuiltInConverters$BufferingResponseBodyConverter.convert(BuiltInConverters.java:103)
at retrofit2.BuiltInConverters$BufferingResponseBodyConverter.convert(BuiltInConverters.java:96)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:225)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:188)
at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:97)
at android.onetap.SynchronizationManager.downloadFile(SynchronizationManager.kt:185)
at android.base.repository.LoginRepository.downloadConfigFilesAndLocalLogin(LoginRepository.kt:349)
at android.base.repository.LoginRepository.access$downloadConfigFilesAndLocalLogin(LoginRepository.kt:48)
at android.base.repository.LoginRepository$loginTask$2.onSRPLoginComplete(LoginRepository.kt:210)
at android.base.repository.LoginRepository$performSyncLogin$srpLogin$1$1.onSRPLogin(LoginRepository.kt:478)
at android.srp.SRPManager$SRPLoginOperation$execute$1.invokeSuspend(SRPManager.kt:323)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:561)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:727)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:667)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:655)
```

Below is screenshot, in that you can see that, I am getting output of file but don't know why it is throwing an exception.

[image]

checked Retrofit's Utils class

https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Utils.java

```
static ResponseBody buffer(final ResponseBody body) throws IOException {
    Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
    body.source().readAll(buffer); <-This line throws an error.
    return ResponseBody.create(body.contentType(), body.contentLength(), buffer);
  }
```

**Update**

Same thing is working fine with enqueue method.

```
response.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody?> {

override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody?>, response: retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody?>) { 
 }
})
```

I have post same issue with Retrofit team, lets see.

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3336

Comment: `myapp.base.AuthenticationManager.checkEnterpriseAccountStatus(AuthenticationManager.kt:492)` sounds relevant to the cause

Comment: Hi, can you please check my updated quetsion

Comment: I have updated logs

Comment: I am sending 7 web request, first it was coming at 5th, 6th and 7th request, now it is started to coming at 6th & 7th web request

Comment: I have updated question with Retrofit's error line, from where error throws, please check

Comment: it seems that the input source is closed for some reason, are you sure you're calling execute only once? Seems you are attempting to read from the same ResponseBody twice and that's not allowed in Retrofit

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi, Yes I am executing it once only, otherwise in logs also I am getting two times request right! but instead i am getting once and that time I am getting an error

Comment: How can you find that "IllegalStateException: closed" is because of Inputsource is closed?

Comment: With the updated stack overflow, now I'm curious about `at android.onetap.SynchronizationManager.downloadFile(SynchronizationManager.kt:185)`

Comment: Yes, it is val response = rulesResourcesServices.getConfigFile(file).execute()

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Thanks to JakeWharton (https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3336), I can be able to get solution.
Actually in my custom interceptor I was reading response by following code

```
Response.body().string()
```

I was doing because above code was helping me to find out that if there is any error than what kind of error it is....

if it is  AUTH_ERROR, I have to generate new token and append it to request header.

According to [retrofit document](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response-body/), if we call any of below method then response will be closed, which means it's not available to consume by the normal Retrofit internals.

```
Response.close()
Response.body().close()
Response.body().source().close()
Response.body().charStream().close()
Response.body().byteStream().close()
Response.body().bytes()
Response.body().string()
```

So to read data, I will use

```
 response.peekBody(2048).string()
```

instead of

```
 response.body().string(),
```

so it will not close response.

below is the final code

```
 val response = chain.proceed(request)
            val body = response.peekBody(Long.MAX_VALUE).string()//<---- Change
            try {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    if (body.contains("status")) {
                        val jsonObject = JSONObject(body)
                        val status = jsonObject.optInt("status")
                        Timber.d("Status = $status")
                        if (status != null && status == 0) {
                            val errorCode = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").optString("error_code")
                            if (errorCode != null) {
                                addRefreshTokenToRequest(request)
                                return chain.proceed(request)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Timber.d("Body is not containing status, might be not valid GSON")
                    }
                }
                Timber.d("End")
                
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Timber.d("Error")
            }
            return response
```

Comment: I have used retrofit with retrofit response in my app. But I am getting need to close the previous call. make sure to close using response.close().

Did you have any solution let me know here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333385/cannot-make-a-new-request-because-the-previous-response-is-still-open-please-ca

Comment: be careful with this approach. if you have responses longer that 2048 bytes Retrofit will throw `java.io.EOFException`

Comment: You can increase value if you get an error because of 2048 bytes, I had to do it as I know that there will be never more value than 2048 bytes from my webservice reponse.

Comment: @SamanSattari JakeWharton mentioned to use `.peekBody(Long.MAX_VALUE)` [in this github comment](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2869#issuecomment-248112784)

Comment: Thanks SamanSattari & Rumit, I have updated my answer

Answer (score 6):

Extending @Siddhpura Amit's answer:
If you don't know the bytes to pass into peak method then you can still use all of the methods, but will just have to create new Response object.

Inside interceptor:

```
okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);
String responseBodyString = response.body().string();

//Do whatever you want with the above string

ResponseBody body = ResponseBody.create(response.body().contentType(), responseBodyString);
return response.newBuilder().body(body).build();
```

Comment: For Kotlin, ResponseBody.create is deprecated. Instead, use:

responseBodyString.toResponseBody(response.body.contentType())

Answer (score 1):

maybe you closed your response in your AuthorizationInterceptor like this

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
   ...
   val response = chain.proceed(builder.build())
   response.close()
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i used  Response.body().string() two times, which is allowed only once. then problem fixed.

Comment: Your answer is a workaround.
Maybe it's best to pinpoint the problem and suggest a more technical solution.