# cannot make a new request because the previous response is still open: please call response.close() in retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java

I cannot make a new request because the previous response is still open: please call `response.close()` in retrofit

```
APIService.userLogin(jobj).enqueue(new Callback<LoginRequest>(){

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginRequest> call, Response<LoginRequest> response) {
            System.out.println(("response ===" + response));
            ApiService getUser1 = RetrofitRequest.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
   
           final Profile profile = Profile.getInstance();
           getUser1.getUser().enqueue(new Callback<GetUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetUser> call, Response <GetUser> response) {
            LoginRequest user = response.body();
            ApiService getUser1 = RetrofitRequest.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
            getUser1.getUser().enqueue(new Callback<GetUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetUser> call, Response <GetUser> response) {
           }
          @Override
          public void onFailure(Call<GetUser> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("GetUseronFailure" + t );
        }
    });
  }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call< LoginRequest > call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println(("ttttttttt ===" + t));
                Log.i(String.valueOf(t), "Response: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```